# THREE.js Exception when using sceneLoader to load scene created by THREE.js Editor

Tags: javascript, three.js

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined` on three.js:12917

The scene file I'm using is:

```
{
"metadata": {
    "version": 4.3,
    "type": "Object",
    "generator": "ObjectExporter"
},
"geometries": [
    {
        "uuid": "7F5BC6A2-4B74-4049-8AF8-40A5EF310430",
        "type": "CubeGeometry",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "depth": 100,
        "widthSegments": 1,
        "heightSegments": 1,
        "depthSegments": 1
    }],
"materials": [
    {
        "uuid": "95D0C78A-2066-4A8D-9F46-73B3038E55DE",
        "type": "MeshBasicMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "opacity": 1,
        "transparent": false,
        "wireframe": false
    }],
"object": {
    "uuid": "E0E0DAAE-012A-49DB-BC1B-2878BCA7F0DA",
    "type": "Scene",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    "children": [
        {
            "uuid": "E60D8291-4E35-4365-A98E-7AEA1D1D433F",
            "name": "Cube 1",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "geometry": "7F5BC6A2-4B74-4049-8AF8-40A5EF310430",
            "material": "95D0C78A-2066-4A8D-9F46-73B3038E55DE",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
        }]
}
```

}

I've checked and it does load successfully and is valid JSON(JSONLint);
I have also tested JSONLoader to successfully load JSON Models.
I seem to be using [the latest version](https://rawgithub.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/build/three.js). The scene was created in the THREE.js Editor, I'm afraid I don't know how to create a scene outside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4259 you should be using ObjectLoader:

```
 function loaded(scene) {
    ...
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
 }

 new THREE.ObjectLoader().load("scene.js", loaded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is with the scene file the editor creates.
I just tried running the scene file through the three.js scene example and got the same error.